# Cleanest way to require the user to enter password to run a program?

Tags: command-line, users, password

What is the cleanest way to require the user to enter password in order to run a particular program without the use of third-party applications? For example, if I type `firefox` to launch it from the terminal, it will prompt for a password and only run it if the correct password is entered. Something akin to that affect using perhaps user permissions.

Comment: which Linux dist are you using ?

Comment: Do you need `firefox` to run in a different security context (i.e. more privileged account)? If yes then you should just use `sudo`. If no, then asking for a password does not accomplish anything since they could just run their own copy that does not require a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create `exampleuser` , and set password to it

then change `firefox` permissions to `700` and change firefore `own` to `exampleruser` ; after this you can run firefox only `root` or `exampleuser` with `sudo` or `su` command.

for exmaple:

```
sudo useradd exampleuser
sudo passwd exampleuser 
sudo chown exampleuser:exampleuser ../firefox 
sudo chmod 700 ../firefox
```

test:

```
$ ../firefox
bash: ../firefox: Permission denied
$ su - exampleuser -c ../firefox
Password:  #<-- type exampleuser password
```

or run with root user:

```
$ sudo ../firefox
[sudo] password for username:  #<-type root password
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use this script to ask password in dialog box then start the app.
If password is correct, then it decrypt the full path of your app to run it.

Before use the script, try to hide your app on your computer, then use this command to encrypt the full path of your app. It ask for your password then encrypt and code in base64, the full path:
`echo -n "/Path/To/Your/Application" | openssl enc -aes256 -a -pbkdf2`

The script require yad to show the dialog box:
`sudo apt install yad`

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Require yad:
# $ sudo apt install yad
#
# Before use it, use these command to get the full path of your application, encrypted and coded in base64, with your password:
# $ echo -n "/Path/To/Your/Application" | openssl enc -aes256 -a -pbkdf2

function main
{
password=$(yad --text-align=center --text="Password" --entry --entry-text="" --hide-text --fixed --title="" --button=OK)

data="xxx" # replace xxx by the full path of your app encrypted and coded in base64 with the upper command

MyApp=$(echo "$data" | openssl enc -aes256 -d -a -pbkdf2 -pass pass:"$password")
$password=""

# test if file exist
if [ -a $MyApp ]
then
    $MyApp # run your application
    exit 0
else
    notify-send "Incorrect" "$x/3"
fi
}

# limit try
x=1
while [ $x -le 3 ]
do
  main
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done

exit 0
```